# Multiple primary artifacts to trigger Azure DevOps release definition

Tags: azure-devops

[image]We have our release definitions in Azure DevOps with multiple sources of artifacts. One of the artifacts being the build artifact and the second being the azure repos Git.

Can the release be triggered whenever there is a new artifact is available (either the build artifact or the azure git repos artifact)? Is this possible in Azure DevOps.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thanks for the information, Could you let me know about the service connection to be provided while configuring the Invoke Rest Api task.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT We are unable to select the service connection in the drop-down list. I have build and release administrator permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understand what you are doing now, you could describe  it in your question, and to use REST API to trigger the release, you can refer this document: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/552318/rest-api-to-trigger-deploy-in-release-pipeline.html

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have added the Invoke Rest API task, Connection type is Generic. But the drop-down list is empty for "Generic Service Connection" even though the service connections are available under Service connection settings.

Comment: We are creating a service connection following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-tfsts

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have created the service connection according to the instructions provided in the link, but the service connection list is empty in the Invoke Rest API task.

Comment: You do not need use that task to resolve this issue, I have update my answer with detailed answer to invoke API to resolve this issue, you can check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add 2 artifacts to a release pipeline. No, (according to your question title) you cannot mark more than 1 artifact as `Primary`. Yes, you can add `CD Triggers` to any number of artifact sources you desire to add to your pipeline.

Beware, CD triggers on repository changes does not necessitate that the artifact you'll be using from the Build source is different that a previous release. I don't know your situation, but I would probably suggest that you have 2 separate `After Release` stages, where each stage applies an artifact filter, so that you only do work with builds when new builds are available and only do work with code when commits are available.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In our case, we have two artifacts (build artifact and Azure Repos Git artifact). We need to auto-trigger CD whenever there is a new artifact generated (new build artifact or git commit). Hope my case is clear now. Do let me know if we can achieve this in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Yes. I believe I was clear about that in my answer. The CD triggers can be added to your artifacts so the the pipeline starts for either of them. This is what was meant by saying `you can add CD Triggers to any number of artifact sources you desire`. Looking at the image I provided, you will see that I have a simple pipeline with a build and repo artifact, and both have CD triggers set.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the release be triggered whenever there is a new artifact is available (either the build artifact or the azure git repos artifact)? Is this possible in Azure DevOps.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Build/Release definitions currently only support a **single trigger**.

As workaround, you could set the `Azure Repos Git artifact` as **primary** artifacts to trigger Azure DevOps release definition.

For the build artifact, we could trigger the release definition from a build task in either build definition through [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Check [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/552318/rest-api-to-trigger-deploy-in-release-pipeline.html) for some more details.

**Update:**

**Detail how to use Rest API trigger release from build pipeline.**

As I answered above, We could use the Rest API [Releases - Update Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-the-release) to trigger the release:

```
PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6
```

When you open a release pipeline, then switch to log tab, you could get the `releaseId` and `environmentId`

[image]

Then, we add a `Inline Powershell` task in the **build pipeline** to invoke the API to trigger the release. The scripts like:

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/Release/releases/285/environments/370?api-version=5.1-preview.6"

$connectionToken="Your PAT Here"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))


$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$body=@"
  {
    "status":"inProgress",
    "scheduledDeploymentTime":null,
    "comment":""
  }
"@
Write-Host "$url"
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method PATCH
```

If you execute this build pipeline, it will trigger the release pipeline.

As test, it works fine on my side.

**Note:**

When you use above scripts, you need go to the Agent Phase and select Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token. See [Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)

**Update2:**

> Powershell script work, but it downloads the old build artifact.
>   However, we need to associate the release with latest build artifact,
>   how can this be accomplished?

You could use another REST API to get the latest Release ID and the `environmentId`:

[Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

We could get the all Release ID for the `definitionId`:

```
"isDeleted": false,
"lastRelease": {
    "id": 285,
    "name": "xxxxxx",
    "artifacts": [],
    "_links": {},
```

Then use `Select-Object -first 1` get the latest Release ID.

Next, we could use another API [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) with `releaseId`, which we get by above Rest API, we could get the `environmentId`:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

The output like:

```
"environments": [
    {
        "id": 370,
        "releaseId": 285,
        "name": "Dev",
        "status": "succeeded",
        "variables": {
```

Now, we get the latest release ID, we could get use the first REST API to trigger the release.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo, Powershell script work, but it downloads the old build artifact. However, we need to associate the release with latest build artifact, how can this be accomplished? Also the can we specify the release name in the body, the behavior now is that same release name (example: Release-1) is created whenever we execute the script.

Comment: @Santhosh, Check the updated2 in my answer, and we could not add the release name in the body.

Comment: How can we trigger the release so that it always downloads the latest build artifact. Thank you.

Comment: @Santhosh, I have answered this question in my update2 answer, we need other two Powershell task to invoke API to get the latest Release ID and environmentId, then transfer those two values to the previous powershell task to trigger release pipeline.